# Query Influx database

Tags: python, influxdb, influxdb-python

I have this code to query a influx DB, but it is not working at all. Here is the python code.

```
import os

from influxdb import InfluxDBClient

username = u'{}'.format(os.environ['INFLUXDB_USERNAME'])
password = u'{}'.format(os.environ['INFLUXDB_PASSWORD'])

client = InfluxDBClient(host='127.0.0.1', port=8086, database='data',
                        username=username, password=password)

result = client.query("SELECT P_askbid_midprice1 FROM 'DCIX_OB' WHERE time > '2018-01-01';")
```

I got the following error, but it's still unclear how to fix the code above. If I query directly from influxdb with bash with `SELECT P_askbid_midprice1 FROM 'DCIX_OB' WHERE time > '2018-01-01';` it worked perfectly fine.

```
    Press ENTER or type command to continue
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "graph_influxdb.py", line 11, in <module>
        result = client.query("SELECT P_askbid_midprice1 FROM 'DCIX_OB' WHERE time > '2018-01-01';")


  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/influxdb/client.py", line 394, in query
    expected_response_code=expected_response_code
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/influxdb/client.py", line 271, in request
    raise InfluxDBClientError(response.content, response.status_code)
influxdb.exceptions.InfluxDBClientError: 400: {"error":"error parsing query: found DCIX_OB, expected identifier at line 1, char 31"}
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

result = client.query("SELECT P_askbid_midprice1 FROM DCIX_OB WHERE time > '2018-01-01'")

this should work

Comment: Yes, indeed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you might be able to use [Pinform](https://github.com/sinarezaei/pinform) which is some kind of ORM/OSTM (Object time series mapping) for InfluxDB.

It can help with designing the schema and building normal or aggregation queries.

```
cli.get_fields_as_series(OHLC,
    field_aggregations={'close': [AggregationMode.MEAN]},
    tags={'symbol': 'AAPL'},
    time_range=(start_datetime, end_datetime),
    group_by_time_interval='10d')
```

Disclaimer: I am the author of this library